# Как определить нажатия мыши без использования Update?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как определить нажатия мыши без использования Update ?

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        transform.DOJump(new Vector3(0,4.2f,3), 10f, 1, 1f, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В Unity "из коробки" нет колбеков от ввода пользователя. События ввода есть в GUI, но это абсолютно разные вещи. Да и сделать такую систему без Update - невозможно.

Можно симулировать такую систему самому с помощью кастомного класса, но в нем все равно придется использовать Update(), проверяя либо все клавиши, либо только те, что вас интересуют.

Простой пример такого класса с событиями от нажатых клавиш:

```
public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour {
    private KeyCode[] keys;

    public static InputManager Instance = null;

    public delegate void KeyEvent(KeyCode key);
    public static event KeyEvent KeyPressed;

    private void Start() {
        if (InputManager.Instance != null && Instance != this) {
            Destroy(gameObject);        
        }
        else {
            Instance = this;
        }

        keys = (KeyCode[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode));
    }

    private void Update() {
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; ++i) {
            if (KeyPressed != null && Input.GetKeyDown(keys[i])) {
                KeyPressed(keys[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант использовать `IPointerClickHandler` и навесить его на какой-нибудь прозрачный элемент канваса, таким образом можно будет отслеживать нажатия мыши без 
непосредственного использования метода `Update()`.

Comment: ИМХО довольно костыльное решение, особенно если система событий вводится в сцену только ради нажатия мыши.